# Sort dictionary by dict value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have such dict:

```
resp = {'1366451044687880192': {'created_at': 'Mon Mar 01 18:11:31 +0000 2021', 'id': 1366463640451233323}, '1366463640451256323': {'created_at': 'Mon Mar 05 19:01:34 +0000 2021', 'id': 1366463640451256323}}
```

Is it possible to sort it by created_at value?

Tried but doesnt work:

```
sorted(resp.values(), key=lambda item: item[0]['created_at'])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sorting dictionary python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089655/sorting-dictionary-python-3)

Comment: If you're sorting on `values()`, then remove the `[0]`... `key=lambda item: item['created_at']`

Comment: Not sure it will give you what you really want. It is just a string. You might want to convert it to a `datetime`

Comment: @Tomerikoo TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: Running your exact code, without the `[0]` gave the correct output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNDoIwEIX3nGJ2QCSm05YKTTgCJzDGVGkikb@UakIMZ8dajbJ0FrOY9@Z9kxkme@k7tixGjwMU8AjAVYhMCJ4i4VxkuywjmNNQfkRvOButrK6Oyrp5WPYdlMoAQcBMIkqGsCGugBKKYfLbqyvn9@mCCU4cgzLGKPOOOVnRv3oqnP4XPQXMJXF0/j/dp7/pwRwMpu5sNPbGpUevl2zvqrnpMYoTuOqpaFR7qhTUVrfS9/36lkMcL8sT)

```
resp = {
    '1366451044687880192': {
        'created_at': 'Mon Mar 01 18:11:31 +0000 2021',
        'id': 1366463640451233323
    },
    '1366463640451256323': {
        'created_at': 'Mon Mar 05 19:01:34 +0000 2021',
        'id': 1366463640451256323
    }
}
print(sorted(resp.values(), key=lambda item: item['created_at']))
```

Output:

```
[
    {'created_at': 'Mon Mar 01 18:11:31 +0000 2021', 'id': 1366463640451233323},
    {'created_at': 'Mon Mar 05 19:01:34 +0000 2021', 'id': 1366463640451256323}
]
```

Or you can sort key-values (items) through ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNDoIwEIX3nGJ2QCSm05YKTTgCJyDEVGkiUX5SuiGGs2OpRlk6i1nMe/O@yYyzvQ09W1ejpxEKeAbgKkQmBE@RcC6yU5YRzGkoP6I3XI1WVjdnZd08LIceSmWAIGAmESVDOBBXQAnFMPnttY3z@3TBBCeOQRljlHnHkuzoXz0VTv@LngLmkjg6/5/u09/0YAlG0/Y2mgbj0qPtJcfW6m6K4gTuei4eqrs0CraZ9L3CutpfU8fxur4A)):

```
sorted(resp.items(), key = lambda item: item[1]['created_at'])
```

which outputs:

```
[
    ('1366451044687880192', {'created_at': 'Mon Mar 01 18:11:31 +0000 2021', 'id': 1366463640451233323}),
    ('1366463640451256323', {'created_at': 'Mon Mar 05 19:01:34 +0000 2021', 'id': 1366463640451256323})
]
```